# How the remote mode in EJB Application works

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am just recently learning about EJB and what I understand up to now that is that the EJB Application provides the main function which is the EJB Container which provides buniness application logic.

For example I have a case like this: an EJB Container running on an JBoss Application Server and containing some logics, ex: return the sum of an Addition.

What happen if my client application is running on another enviroment, how can my client application connect to the EJB Container?, for example via WLAN/WIFI. 
Because I am creating a scenario that my client application can connect to the JBoss Application Server and do some logics in the AS (ex: receive data from the AS), so I just think about EJB which might sastify my task.

I did find some tutorials about EJB, but most of these tutorials are about either the EJB Container and Servlet or the EJB Container and Client Java Application are on the same machine, because I saw that they are creating on the same Project, therefore the client is easily to access to the EJB Container. But what if now I have them in separate enviroment?

Any ideas are welcome and I appreciate for that. If possible can anyone give me some tutorial. Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is discussed in this link, [EJB on Wildfly calling remote EJB from another Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603982/ejb-on-wildfly-calling-remote-ejb-from-another-wildfly)

For more details about this, you can refer to the tutorial here, https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI.

and as an example, you can refer to this, https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-sandbox-quickstarts/tree/b5714e49dd1bb5e60233506b62f98b2ea5b88c0a/ejb-security-propagation.
Hope this helps!